# Problems with Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to execute a Javascript function when my ASP.NET page loads.  The purpsose of the Javascript is to display some controls based on the checked status of their corresponding checkboxes.

I have used the line:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "sethiddenMoSESfields", True)
```

where sethiddenMoSESfields is the name of my Javascript function.

Here is the function:

```
function sethiddenMoSESfields() {
var chkgpstatus = document.getElementById("chkGP");
var chknursestatus = document.getElementById("chkNurse");
if (chkgpstatus.checked) {
    $('#ddlGP').show();
}
if (chknursestatus.checked) {
    $('#ddlNurse').show();
}
```

}

The problem is that is does not appear to be rendering correctly when the page is loaded and I receive the following error:

> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

The error is occurring because the page is rendering the function call like this:

```
sethiddenMoSESfields
(function(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e) {
        e.dispose = function() {
            Array.remove(Page_ValidationSummaries, document.getElementById(id));
        }
        e = null;
    }
})('valsum_GPSEA');
```

For some reason is it writing another function call (relating to my validation control) as a parameter to my sethiddenMoSESfields function call.  I have no idea why it is doing that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have another function named `sethiddenMoSESfields` in your code somewhere

Comment: Yes, the sethiddenMoSESfields function is included in a seperate script file called utilities.js that is referenced in the page.

Comment: So rename your function as the current name is conflicting with the other function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be calling the method wrongly. The 3rd parameter to `RegisterStartupScript` should be the actual script you want to execute. In your case this would be "sethiddenMoSESfields();" if you already have the function definition included in the HTML.

If not, you'd have to put the entire sethiddenMoSESfields function definition, followed by `sethiddenMoSESfields();` in the string. Something like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addScript", @"
        function sethiddenMoSESfields() {
            var chkgpstatus = document.getElementById('chkGP');
            var chknursestatus = document.getElementById('chkNurse');
            if (chkgpstatus.checked) {
                $('#ddlGP').show();
            }
            if (chknursestatus.checked) {
                $('#ddlNurse').show();
            }
        }
        sethiddenMoSESfields();", true);
```

I changed the " to ' to make it easier to escape. Also, it would be better to change the 1st parameter to a page specific type.

---

The validation script you are seeing is actually meant to be there and is not related to how you are calling `RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: The sethiddenMoSESfields is contained with a seperate script file called utilities.js that is referenced by the page in the toolscriptmanager tag.

Comment: The problem with the validation script is that it is appearing with the bracket of the sethiddenMoSESfields() function so that it thinks its a parameter.

Comment: @NHSbaz - for your first comment, then you don't need the full script, just do the call alone (i.e. add `();` to your 3rd parameter. for your 2nd comment, the brackets for the validation are not sethiddenMoSESfields's. They are part of the self invocation of the validation script. Try not calling RegisterStartupScript and examine the HTML.

Comment: It was the missing brackets!

Thanks a million.

Comment: No worries! Have a great weekend!